# Trouble getting Vue component to render when seperated into a new component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my location view I had a Vuetify dialog setup that deletes a location from a list. I now have a second list for Users that will have the same functionality and dialog so I though this would be a good time to refactor and move my delete dialog into a component. Below it works as intended but when I move into a component I must be missing something, any pointers?

```
<template>
    <v-dialog
          v-model="dialogDelete"
          max-width="500px"
          persistent
        >
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title class="headline">
              Delete location
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn
                @click="closeDeleteDialog"
              >
                Cancel
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn
                v-if="permissions.locations.delete"
                @click="deleteItem"
              >
                Delete
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
</template>
```

Then I have my script:

```
data: () => ({
  dialog: false,
  dialogDelete: false
},
methods: {
    deleteItem () {
      this.$store.dispatch('deleteFirebaseDoc', { docId: this.locationId, collection: 'locations' })

      this.locationId = null
      this.dialogDelete = false
    },
    deleteItemConfirm (item) {
      this.locationId = item.docId
    },
    closeDeleteDialog () {
      this.dialogDelete = false
    } }
```

When moving this into a components I don't get any errors but I also have no dialog:

```
<DeleteDialog v-model="dialogDelete" title="Delete location?"/>
```

Script is the same as above but I include my component:

```
  components: {
    DeleteDialog: () => import('@/components/Shared/DeleteDialog')
  },
```

Then I have my DeleteDialog.vue component setup as follows:

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    max-width="500px"
    persistent
  >
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title
        class="headline"
      >
        <slot name="header">
          {{ title }}
        </slot>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <slot name="body">
          {{ message }}
        </slot>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer />
        <v-btn
          color="grey darken-1"
          text
          @click="$emit(closeDeleteDialog)"
        >
          Cancel
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
          color="primary darken-1"
          text
          @click="$emit(deleteItem)"
        >
          Delete
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DeleteDialog',
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    message: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  emits: ['closeDeleteDialog', 'deleteItem']
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any value bound to the v-dialog in component. If you wish to pass props to the native v-dialog from parent scope, you can extend v-dialog and bind all attributes and events to your custom component. To be more clear:

DeleteDialog.vue

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
    // your attributes
  >
  // ...
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
import {VDialog } from "vuetify/lib"
export default {
  extends: VDialog,
  // ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the comment but still not clear what I would have to change in my code

Comment: just add in DeleteDialog.vue the lines that are missing from your code (`v-bind="$props"`, `v-on="$listeners"`, `import { VDialog } from "vuetify/lib"` and `extends: VDialog`

Comment: Ah great! I do get an Error: "Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined, any idea?

Comment: try importing VDialog from "vuetify" instead of "vuetify/lib"

Comment: Thank Igor, I actually import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framwork' and plan to use tree-shaking. Do I still need to extend it in the  DeleteDialog.vue component then?

Comment: you're right. in this situation just binding attributes and listeners will be enough. Also, I've noticed a mistake in my answer: it should be `$attrs` instead of `$props`

Comment: Thans you. Last question I hope!! ... Property or method "deleteItem" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. Something obvoius?

Comment: In `@click="$emit(deleteItem)"`, $emit accepts as first argument a string name of the event. So it should be `@click="$emit('deleteItem')"`. The same apply for `closeDeleteDialog`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229173/discussion-between-pianoc-and-igor-moraru).